# How to convert Python ASCII value to it's hexidecimal value (in bytes)

Tags: python, byte

The ASCII value `a` has an integer value of `97` and a Hex value of `61`

Going between its integer value of `97`and ASCII representation (with `ord` and `chr`) is easy, however, I would like to convert the string to a `bytes` object with its hex value of `61` I think this would look like `b'a'` or `bx\67`

Additionally, how can I then convert the bytes object back into the integer value?

Comment: Didn't you delete a very long post with a vast amounts of comments earlier that was asking this?

Comment: `bytes('a','ASCII')` ?

Comment: @JonClements I did a very bad job asking what I meant to ask in that post.

Comment: @Startec then that's why you could have [edited your previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211263/python-3-simple-string-to-integer-conversion) to clarify - having kept the comments and context in place, so more information is available as to what you're trying to achieve and what other people have already spent their time prompting you towards - rather than just deleting it and re-posting.

Comment: @JonClements, I wish I would have done that.  The post (due to my own poor writing) was closed and I think my edits permanently messed it up.  Believe me, I learned a lot about SO (and bytes) from this.

Comment: @Startec pleased to hear that - best wishes moving forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> b = bytes('a', 'ascii')
>>> b
b'a'
>>> b[0]
97
```

Your distinction between hex and decimal seems odd. Are you aware that `97` is *exactly* the same in memory as `0x61`? A number does not have a base - only a representation of a number has a base. So it doesn't make sense to talk about a `bytes` object containing hex values as opposed to decimal values.

Comment: Your comment helps me a lot. I am aware that `97` == `0x61`, however, what lead to my confusion is the following
`b'a' == bytes([97]) = True` but `b'a' == b'\x61 = False`.  I wanted to make sure I had the hex value representing the integer `97`, not the byte with a hex value of `97`, which would be an integer of `151`. Sorry, that sounds unclear, but do you understand my confusion?

Comment: `b'a' == b'\x61'` returns `True` for me. Still, I think I understand what you were confused about.

Comment: Also, just correcting your terminology - an "integer" is a number which can be represented in (among infinite other bases!) base-10 ("decimal") or base-16 ("hex"). So 151 is an integer, and so is 0x61, and so is 0b010110, etc. You may avoid a bit of confusion in later questions by changing your language a little :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"\x67".encode("hex")
```

but I dont think you can do that in python 3 I think its more like

```
codecs.encode("\x67","hex") #maybe??
```